# android: get image from API via HTTPS

Tags: android, image, https

**My API request:** _HTTPS://myserver/getcaptchaimage?accesstoken=mytoken&userid=123

**Response:** Captcha Image

**Header:**

Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    **image/png**
Date    Mon, 04 Jul 2016 09:15:05 GMT
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Please tell me how to get response and load to ImageView in Android.

My Code (exception when https.connect())

```
private void getCaptchaImageFromServer() {
        String URL = ServerPath.SERVER_PATH_GET_CAPTCHA_IMAGE + "?accesstoken=" + UserInforLogin.getInstance(this).getToken()
                + "&userid=" + UserInforLogin.getInstance(this).getUserId();
        LogUtils.e("test-request captcha image", URL);

        try {
            URL imageURL = new URL(URL);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageviewTest);

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
            SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            context.init(null, new X509TrustManager[] {new NullX509TrustManager()}, new SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

            HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) imageURL.openConnection();
            https.connect();
            InputStream input = https.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            LogUtils.e("test-request captcha image ERROR", "ERROR");
        }

    }
```

Comment: can you getting json response??

Comment: Use Third party library for better performance and Easy Code.
Example:
`Picasso.with(getContext())
                .load(URL)
.into(imageView);`

See http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @VishalPatoliya : no, response content type is image/png, not json

Comment: @kashyapjimuliya: i try to use Picasso but it is not working :(

Comment: I don't get the problem. You get an error?

Comment: @Memme: yes, i get exception when call https.connect(), and Picasso can not load this captcha image to imageview :(

Comment: URL is the location of the Image on your server. Right? If not, post the Response and Log.

Comment: Can you post the exception log?

Answer (score 0):

You can use other third party library for image

1. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
2. [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)